# Return non existing IDs

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of IDs and I write a MYSQL query to get information about these IDs.

What I need is a way to figure out which IDs are no longer in the database to delete them from the list of IDs.

Is there an easy solution to do that which I just can't think of right now?

Comment: return all ids from the db and compare them against an array of ids. remove ones that don't match

Comment: Where is this "list" of ids? In another table? In a PHP array? ..?

Comment: The list is basically a php array that I need to compare with a table in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Create an additional (temporary) table, populate it with a list of IDs, and execute the query to find non existing id. For example -

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp(id INT);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES (1), (2), (8), (10);

-- View non existing ID:
SELECT t.id FROM temp t
  LEFT JOIN your_table a 
    ON a.id = t.id
  WHERE a.id IS NULL;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
```

Then read this dataset in php application and update the list of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

This is written not knowing your table structure, and thus making one up off the top of my head, but...

If you have two tables, ID and INFO, like:

```
ID (IDCOL int, DATEENTERED datetime)
INFO (INFOID int, ID_ID int, ID_NAME varchar(50))
```

Then you could query

```
SELECT * FROM ID WHERE IDCOL NOT IN (SELECT ID_ID FROM INFO)
```

And that should return all entries in ID where there is not corresponding entry in INFO.

After that it's a case of writing appropriate delete statements.

The whole thing could be done in one step with

```
DELETE FROM ID WHERE IDCOL NOT IN (SELECT ID_ID FROM INFO)
```

But I generally prefer to do my deletes in defined transactions where you can examine to make sure you haven't screwed it up before you commit the changes to the DB.

Comment: And I see from the comments above that my answer is way off base due to the fact that it's not all in the database :)